# Windows Server Backup 2008 R2 bare-metal to network share incremental - is previous backup lost if backup fails?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2

In the backup config panels, Windows Server Backup warns that with backup to a network share, the previous backups are overwritten.  What I haven't figured out is whether a failed backup results in NO backup, or if the failed backup is just dropped, leaving the previous backup in-tact.  In this scenario, the previous backup would be erased only after a successful subsequent backup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Failed Backup results in NO backup.

Comment: Ok.  Well that is very lame -- Is that documented or from personal experience or what?

Comment: Thanks for answering - but if you have any additional information, such as documentation/references, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a .vhd file in your share location, attach it in disk management, then tell Windows Server Backup to use that as if it were a locally attached drive.